# Change unconfined_u to system_u is failing

Tags: linux, centos, selinux

I've got a file on my apache/linux server. ls -Z gives:

```
drwxr-xr-x. apache   apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 localization.smicloud.org
```

I need to change unconfined_u to system_u like all my other dirs.

I have been googling and on several places I found info that this is how to do it:

> semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t localization.smicloud.org

and

> semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t localization.smicloud.org

Those give following error:

> libsemanage.get_home_dirs: netbeans homedir /var/www/html or its
>   parent directory conflicts with a file context already specified in
>   the policy.  This usually indicates an incorrectly defined system
>   account.  If it is a system account please make sure its uid is less
>   than 500 or its login shell is /sbin/nologin.

I'm not really sure why netbeans is mentioned. It is my development tool but it's not present in the information about the directory. The directory is empty!

How can I fix this?

**Update**

I wasn't to clear about my real problem: I am trying to use Netbeans to ftp my files to this folder. It works for all other folders and the only difference I can see between this and those is this part.

Comment: Correct, that answer did solve my question. But it wasn't the root cause of my real issue...

Comment: See also an answer that provides a solution for setting the user context.  In summary, the restorecon -F flag is required to modify user context.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/379029/22653

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't *need* to change this if you're using the default *targeted* SELinux policy; it's ignored.

Comment: Ok. I wasn't really to clear what my problem really was. I am trying to use Netbeans to ftp my files to this folder. It works for all other folders and the only difference I can see between this and those is this part. Is this still irrelevant? Updating my question.

Comment: You should probably completely rewrite your question from scratch.

Comment: You actually answered the question I asked and that is that it's not needed.